# dotm creates new document - how to remove the reference to the template?

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-word

I have a dotm with macros stored in it. When a new document is created, there is a reference to the dotm file (if you're looking at the project in VBA editor) which I need to eliminate.

Is it somehow possible to do this with VBA code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sever the original reference by replacing it with a reference to another template using the `Attachedtemplate` property. For example:

```
Private Sub Document_New()

ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate = "C:\Users\Joe\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Normal.dotm"

End Sub
```

Comment: Will word on an other computer question the user for that dot file when I change that to an empty dot file? It is important that this document can be sent to other users which have no access to the dot files.

Comment: @wullxz - Every Word document is based on an originating (attached) template. Microsoft knows that if documents (based on a template existing only on the originating PC) raised errors when they were emailed to other computers, millions of people would never be able to share documents. So emailing a document from your PC that was based on a unique template or attached to a unique template should not create an issue. However, emailing a .docm file with offending code or a template that references other templates is another matter altogether.